# ng-if not behaving as expected

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have an angular expression `{{ userInfo.activities.ids }}`, it is an array which I am sending to angular through php.
Now I need to check a value in this array,
I am using this :-

`[[userInfo.activities.ids.indexOf(1) != -1]]` and It returns true or false.
I wanted to apply `ng-if` on basis of it's value.
Therefore I wrote:

```
<input ng-if="{{userInfo.activities.ids.indexOf(1) != -1}} == true" checked type="checkbox">
<input ng-if="{{userInfo.activities.ids.indexOf(1) == -1}} == true" type="checkbox">
```

But `ng-if` is not verifying  condition and therefore none of the input gets displayed.

Please suggest what method I can use instead of this?
For separating my template from angular expression I have used [[]] interpolates.
I am using angular along with laravel 5.2 php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your braces in the `ng-if` condition,

If you are using the scope variables in the angular models such as `ng-if, ng-model, ng-class` etc, there is no need to use the interpolation(curly-braces).

Also as your expression evaluates either true or false, you no need to again check `== true` condition

```
<input ng-if="((userInfo.activities.ids.indexOf(1)) != -1)" checked type="checkbox">
<input ng-if="((userInfo.activities.ids.indexOf(1)) == -1)" type="checkbox">
```

[Here is a reference](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-if.asp)

Comment: Let me implement and check the solution. Thanks @Sravan.

Comment: Its working. Thanks!! It also worked when I applied ng-if="{{userInfo.activities.ids.indexOf(1) != -1}} == 'true'". i.e when I put true/false in quotes. Thanku for HELP.

Comment: This are the worst condiitions i have seen in my 2 year career as frontend developer. Use the checks of my answer

Answer (score 3):

Please check your array like this:

```
<input ng-if="userInfo.activities.ids[0] === -1" type="checkbox"> // if the value is a number
<input ng-if="userInfo.activities.ids[0] === '-1'" type="checkbox"> // it its a string
<input ng-if="userInfo.activities.ids.length === 0'" type="checkbox"> // if its empty
```

The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal. Always use === or !==

Comment: I have to check Index of 1,2,3 and so in my array and on basis of that i have to apply checked. As explained in question. Thanks for help @codeNashor.